# How do I get the source code of webview in chrome app

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-app, whatsapp

I am trying to make a chrome app to display the realtime html source code of the webview.

- Need help to get the source code of webview element. The below code is not working.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <webview id="wa_webview" src="https://www.google.com/" autosize="on"></webview>
        <br>
        <h2 id="heading">Source Code</h2>
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('popup.html', {
        'id': 'window_launcher',
        'outerBounds': {
            'width': 1200,
            'height': 900
        }
    });
});


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    let view = document.getElementById('wa_webview');

    view.addContentScripts([{
        name: 'contentScript',
        matches: ['*://google.com/*'],
    }]);

    view.executeScript(
    {code: 'document.documentElement.innerHTML'},
    function(results) {
        var source = results[0];
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = source; 
    });

});
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('div').textContent = document.querySelector('#wa_webview').innerHtml`

Comment: How do I use it in the above code?

Comment: No idea about Angular, my code was plain JavaScript.